# ApexCharts in SolidJS: updating the chart is getting progressively slower after many updates

Tags: apexcharts, solid-js

It's a Tauri application with SolidJS in the frontend, running on Windows. The goal is visualizing data produced by the backend in a line chart with ApexCharts. There is only one series with exactly 100 points. New data is push()-ed into an array that is shift()-ed when the length reaches 100. The chart is updated when new data is received, approximately twice per second.
Problem: after a few hundred data elements, updating the chart gets very slow, and CPU load produced by the webview goes up (Note: there is still only 100 points in the series). Eventually, updating the chart takes several seconds and cannot keep up with the backend anymore. There is no issue if I keep everything else in place, just dont update the chart and log the data into a messages view. It does not get any slower even after several hours.

What I tried:

- In the first version the array was stored in a signal. Got slow with
  time.
- Tried to use a store instead of the signal to keep the array. Did not expect any
  change, and it realy did not help, just saw stores more often in
  examples.
- Next version, directly updating the data without using
  SolidJS reactivity:

  ApexCharts.exec('tempchart', 'updateSeries', [
  {
  data: chartdata
  }
  ]);

  Did not help, either.
- My last idea was using the appendData() method in a similar way as above and adding the data one by one directly to the chart. For some reason this does not seem to be working, I can't see any updates in the chart. But no error, either. Called render() after appendData() to no avail.

What's wrong with this, how do we visualize live data with ApexCharts? Is this a known issue with ApexCharts, or with its integration into SolidJS?
I'm interested in your experience with ApexCharts using React and other frameworks, and other chart components in any framework.

The code is here:
https://github.com/vjalle/Tauri

Update: dropped ApexCharts and moved to [www.chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org). Works like a charm, no slowing down anymore.

Comment: Ehh... It's totally unusable and embarrassing that everyone can see it now, but made public anyway: https://github.com/vjalle/Tauri
Thanks for looking into it and hope you can find something. You should be able to build it, select 127.0.0.1 from the dropdown, start the monitoring and enable simulation. I'm not sure whether the issue will manifest, I have an embedded device sending UDP frames with the data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an extra wrapper library to use ApexCharts in Solid JS. Just import the library and use it so that you can have full control over the chart.

Here we created an element inside the component body and render the chart, later insert it into the component. It seem `ApexCharts` checks if element is inserted into the body when rendering, giving an error if element is not inserted yet. However, it works.

```js
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'
import { createEffect, createSignal, onMount } from 'solid-js';

const generateData = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 100 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 ));
}

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = createSignal(generateData());

  var options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'sales',
      data: data(),
    }],
    xaxis: {
      categories: [...data().map((_, i) => i * 1000)]
    },
  };

  const el = document.createElement('div');
  const chart = new ApexCharts(el, options);

  createEffect(() => {
    console.log(data().length);
    chart.updateSeries([{
      data: data(),
    }]);
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    setData(generateData())
  }, 1000);
  
  onMount(() => {
    chart.render();
  });
  
  return (
    <div>{el}</div>
  );
};
```

Alternatively we can use `onMount` hook to render the chart directly on the component when component mounts. Previously mentioned error will be gone now since chart is rendered after the element mounts onto the DOM tree.

Here we need to defer running the effect because otherwise we will be updating data immediately. Plus, chart will be undefined since `createEffect` runs before `onMount`. I kept the previous example's as is for contrast. Otherwise, it should also be deferred.

```js
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'
import { createEffect, createSignal, on, onMount } from 'solid-js';

const generateData = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 100 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 ));
}

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = createSignal(generateData());

  var options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'sales',
      data: data(),
    }],
    xaxis: {
      categories: [...data().map((_, i) => i * 1000)]
    },
  };

  let ref: HTMLDivElement;
  let chart: ApexCharts;

  onMount(() => {
    chart = new ApexCharts(ref!, options);
    chart.render();
  });

  createEffect(on(data, () => {
    console.log(data().length);
    chart.updateSeries([{ data: data() }]);
  }, { defer: true }));

  setInterval(() => {
    setData(generateData())
  }, 1000);
  
  return (
    <div ref={ref!}></div>
  );
};
```

Important point is we do not keep inserting data, but update in batches.

If you need to keep the previously rendered data in your signal, you can derive a slice of it. Say your data inside the signal is is 1000 element long, you can keep a cursor and extract a slice of it.

```js
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'
import { createEffect, createSignal, on, onMount } from 'solid-js';

const generateData = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 1000 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 ));
}

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = createSignal(generateData());

  const slice = () => data().slice(0, 100);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'sales',
      data: slice(),
    }],
    xaxis: {
      categories: [...slice().map((_, i) => i * 1000)]
    },
  };

  let ref: HTMLDivElement;
  let chart: ApexCharts;

  onMount(() => {
    chart = new ApexCharts(ref!, options);
    chart.render();
  });

  createEffect(on(slice, () => {
    console.log(slice().length);
    chart.updateSeries([{ data: slice() }]);
  }, { defer: true }));

  setInterval(() => {
    setData(generateData())
  }, 1000);
  
  return (
    <div ref={ref!}></div>
  );
};
```

This runs OK, will be much smoother in production but since rendering is memory intensive process, a large data size causes excessive fan noise and heating.

The sluggishness you mention is caused by how ApexCharts are implemented. If you inspect the rendered DOM elements, you will see whole chart DOM is re-created for each each update cycle, meaning previously rendered chart is discarded and a new one is built from scratch.

So it is not good for rendering large data sizes that changes frequently. Check if there is any chart type or an API to re-use already rendered elements after making style and position changes. If not you can either down-sample your data to a few nodes instead of 100 and reduce update frequencies, or use another library.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I could definitely downsample the data and reduce the update frequency, but that would only buy some time: it would still get slower, maybe after a longer time and more updates than it does now. I guess I'll try other chart components. I need it running for at least a full day without crashing or getting too slow.

Comment: @vjalle Does the chart has to use the whole of the accumulated data or display last n number of elements as new values arrive?

Comment: Only the last n elements, and n is currently 100. The code never provides more than 100 elements to the graph. Before pushing new data to the end of the array, the first one is removed. It works, looks good, the only issue is that it's getting progressively slower with time, and I don't understand, why.

Comment: @vjalle I tried second example  10 nodes and per second updates and fan noise never stopped. It seems ApexChart is memory intensive. Memory profile shows it leaks some memory but not that terrible but I ran about a few minutes. If you need only line charts, you can create your own. It is not that hard. Otherwise like Alex Lohr said, it is best if you use use more light weight and battle tested libraries.

Comment: Thanks, will look for another chart lib. Can't create mine, just started with JS and web apps.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable data like the one required for ApexCharts is bad for performance and memory consumption.

Ideally, you'd like to keep your data in a store, so only changes are propagated, and use something like d3.js to get the required props to render the charts in solid.

Jack Herrington did a nice demonstration of this principle on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xt1dNdJpgw4.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, neither stores nor signals work, and keeping the data in a variable and updating directly is not any better. It seems that this is an issue with ApexCharts itself - it's probably not designed for my use case.